# What's the most effective way to update my remote repository after changing it locally?

Tags: django, git, bitbucket

So I've pushed my Django project to Bitbucket. However after I make changes to it offline, I want to update the remote repo. How would I go about this?

Comment: Er, `git push`?

Comment: Well, there is more than just `git push` but, you need a tutorial on git. Normally, you need to first `add`,`commit` and then `push`.

Comment: What do you mean by effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems `git push` will do the job, if you have commited your changes.

But I am pretty sure you want to read up on git before you touch a remote repo.

- [git cheat sheet](https://services.github.com/on-demand/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf)
- [Official git reference](https://git-scm.com/docs)
- [Pro Git, the one and only book, pdf](https://github.com/progit/progit2/releases/download/2.1.17/progit.pdf)